# How to remove/delete executable files (aka files without extension) only

Tags: c++, linux, unix, file

I have a directory src/ that contain many .cc files and its binary.
For example:

```
src/
  |_ foo.cc
  |_ bar.cc
  |_ qux.cc
  |_ thehead.hh
  |_ foo  (executable/binary)
  |_ bar  (executable/binary)
  |_ qux  (executable/binary)
  |_ makefile
```

In reality there are many .cc and executable files.

I need to remove those binaries in a global way without having to list
all the files. Is there a fast and compact way to do it?

I tried:

```
$ rm *
```

but it removes all the files include .cc and .hh files.

I am aware of this command:

```
$ rm foo bar qux ....
```

but then we still have to list all the files one by one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can run

```
find . -perm +100 -type f -delete
```

Comment: Just for clarity, this only checks whether the user's exec bit is set, and it's using deprecated syntax.  See man find for the gory details.

Answer (score 20):

Here you go:

```
ls | grep -v "\." | xargs rm
```

The `grep -v` says "only allow filenames that don't contain a dot", and the `xargs rm` says "then pass the list of filenames to `rm`".

Comment: @Richie: thanks. Is there a way to exclude "makefile"? Which we want to keep.

Comment: @foolishbrat: Just add another grep: ls | grep -v "\." | grep -v makefile | xargs rm

Comment: how about excluding subdirectories? guessing you need to use `find` instead of `ls` for that? also, you can exclude files with `.` and `Makefile` with one `grep` like so: `ls | grep -v "\.\|Makefile"`

Comment: complete mess and misleading. I wonder about so many upvotes.

Comment: DON'T PARSE LS https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Answer (score 13):

Use the `find`. What you want is this:

```
find . -type f -executable -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Removing everything without an extension can also be done:

```
find . -type f -not -iname "*.*" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

The former option does not delete the `Makefile`, and is thus to be preferred. I think [kcwu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856463/how-to-remove-delete-executable-files-aka-files-without-extension-only/856486#856486) shows a nice way to improve the above using the `-delete` option :

```
find . -type f -executable -delete
find . -type f -not -iname "*.*" -delete
```

---

**Edit**: I use GNU findutils `find`, version 4.4.0, under Ubuntu 8.10. I was not aware the `-executable` switch is so uncommon.

Comment: @Stephan: I got "find: -executable: unknown option"

Comment: What find are you using?  -executable doesn't work for me.  However, I can do use -perm /ugo+x with GNU find.

Comment: @foolishbrat: perhaps you're using an older option of find. Try kcwu's answer.

Comment: @Matthew: I updated the answer. I suppose most alternatives to -executable are more portable.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 (only one version behind, albeit LTS).

Comment: If you add the switch -type f to the first suggestion, it wil be perfect. Otherwise, on my linux CenOS subdirs are also considered as executables. However the deletion fails fortunately.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather go for a *clean* target in the Makefile. Most probably it already contains a list of these binaries, so adding a *clean* target would not require much effort.

Comment: And it's safer. Just think about what happens if you use one of the other grep'ish solutions and someone decides that it would be a good idea to have a "README" file ;-)

Comment: How would you write the `make clean` target to remove all the compiled executables? I thought that was the point of the `find` and `ls | grep` type answers, to put under `clean:` and catch all the executables? Or am I missing a point somewhere?

Comment: Makefiles are made of static instructions describing a map which sources files are used to generate a specific target file and how. Therefore you usually have a list of all possible target executables in a variable named TARGETS or similar.

Comment: so is it actually a better practice to specifically list out every single executable in the `Makefile`'s _clean_ target?

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -perm /ugo+x -delete
```

Corrected version of Stephan202's first command.

EDIT: Also try:

```
find . -perm /111 -delete
```

which uses the octal equivalent

Comment: @Matt: under MacOsX, I get this: find: -perm: /ugo+x: illegal mode string

Comment: On my Mac, the following works: `find . -type f -perm +ugo=x` finds files that are executable for **any** of `ugo`, `find . -type f -perm -ugo=x` finds files that are executable for **all** of `ugo`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `-exec rm '{}' \;` to find one can use `-delete` arg.

Answer (score 2):

Use find to remove all files (not folders) that do not contain a dot characeter:

```
find . \! -name "*.*" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: absence of . doesn't mean it is executable

Answer (score 2):

i suggest using first

```
find . -not -name "*.*" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

to see the name of files that are matched.

and then, change the ls -l to rm

```
find . -not -name "*.*" -exec rm {} \;
```

also, you can use a confirm prompt to make it more safe:

```
find . -not -name "*.*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

`findutils` deprecated `+omode` syntax, now you can use `/omode` instead:

```
find . -perm /100 -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just compile your executables in `/bin` and simply `rm /bin/*`.
Simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I obtain so many methods from your answer~
And I want to share with you a method, though it's not very concise.
With `ls -F`, you can get files with `*` or `/`, which are executable file and directory. And then you can `rm` them with `sed`, this method is useful in some situation such as `a.out` file. The Bash code is as follows.

```sh
rm `ls -F |grep \*|sed 's/.$//'`
```